# Got nil when download image link from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I try to upload multiple images from library to Firebase storage. The upload process works perfectly, all the images is on Firebase storage but when i try to download the image url link to save in database, it shows nil. Please help me how to fix this? Thank a lot

```
for imageData in ArrayMedia {
    print(imageData)
    let filePath = "\(currentUserId)/\(key)"
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageData, 0.3)
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"

    storageReference.child(filePath).putData(data!, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metaData, error) in
        print(metadata)
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        } else {
            let PhotoUrl = metadata.downloadURL()?.absoluteString // GOT NIL IN THIS LINE
            print(PhotoUrl)
            let value = ["Username" : currentUserName, "UserId" : currentUserId, "Text" : self.tvPost.text] as [String : Any]
            databaseReference.child("PendingPost").child(currentUserId).child(key).updateChildValues(value)
            databaseReference.child("PendingPost").child(currentUserId).child(key).child("Images").child(key).setValue(["PhotoUrl": PhotoUrl])
        }
        self.showAlert()
    })
}
```

Comment: When you print `metadata`, does the `downloadURL` is displayed in the console ?

Comment: it shows this FIRStorageMetadata 0x60000015f740: {
    contentType = "image/jpg";
    name = "A7IH5SmxnmXm8wGuJxR3XijP7Hl2/250520182102";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to use this instead :**

```
storageRef.child(path).putData(data, metadata: metaData){ (metaData,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            } else {
                let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
            }
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: Perfect answer, my problem is that i wrote wrong variable. Should be metaData, not metadata. Thank a lot